# Write code that finds the ripple of a function (existing code finds the wrong answer)

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, summation, physics, code-review

I have the following code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
u = 5;
\[Tau] = (1/2)*10^(-3);
c = 10^(-6);
r = 1000;
y = u*Sum[((1 - E^((-t + \[Tau] + 4 n \[Tau])/(c*r)))  HeavisideTheta[
        t - 4 n \[Tau]] HeavisideTheta[
        t - \[Tau] - 4 n \[Tau]]) - ((1 - E^((-t + (3 + 4 n) \[Tau])/(
         c*r))) HeavisideTheta[t - 4 n \[Tau]] HeavisideTheta[
        t - (3 + 4 n) \[Tau]]), {n, 0, Infinity}];
```

If I plot (`Plot[y,{t,0,15*10^(-3)},GridLines->{{(2*6+3)*\[Tau],(2*6+1)*\[Tau]},{y/.t->(2*6+3)*\[Tau],y/.t->(2*6+1)*\[Tau]}}]`) the solution `y`, I get the following picture:

[image]

Now, we can see that the maximum and the minimum of the function $y(t)$ is found at the following times: $t=(2\text{k}+3)\tau$ and $t=(2\text{k}+1)\tau$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

> Question: I want to find the absolute difference between the maximum and minimum when $t\to\infty$.

---

**My work:**

Mathematically speaking, I want to find:

$$\lim_{\text{k}\to\infty}\left|\text{y}\left(\left(2\text{k}+3\right)\tau\right)-\text{y}\left(\left(2\text{k}+1\right)\tau\right)\right|\tag1$$

I know that the answer to the question must be:

$$\frac{5 (e-1)}{1+e}\approx2.31059\tag2$$

Coding this in Mathematica gave me:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[Abs[(y /. t -> (2*k + 3)*\[Tau]) - (y /. 
      t -> (2*k + 1)*\[Tau])], k -> Infinity]]

Out[1]=Interval[{0, 20}]
```

Which is wrong. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There 2 typo in **My work**. First, let plot function `y`, local minimum and maximum in one plot as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"];
u = 5;
\[Tau] = (1/2)*10^(-3);
c = 10^(-6);
r = 1000;
y = u*Sum[((1 - E^((-t + \[Tau] + 4 n \[Tau])/(c*r))) HeavisideTheta[
        t - 4 n \[Tau]] HeavisideTheta[
        t - \[Tau] - 4 n \[Tau]]) - ((1 - 
         E^((-t + (3 + 4 n) \[Tau])/(c*r))) HeavisideTheta[
        t - 4 n \[Tau]] HeavisideTheta[t - (3 + 4 n) \[Tau]]), {n, 0, 
     Infinity}];
 Show[Plot[y, {t, 0, .01}], 
 ListPlot[{Table[({t, y} /. t -> (2*k + 1)*\[Tau]), {k, {1, 3, 5, 7, 
       9}}], Table[({t, y} /. t -> (2*k + 1)*\[Tau]), {k, {2, 4, 6, 
       8}}]} // N, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Therefore, we have minimum for even `k` , and maximum for odd `k` (Note, that it is not $2k+3$ and $2k +1$ like in the code `In[1]:`). Let define local extremum as follows

```
dy = (y /. t -> (2*k + 1)*\[Tau]);
```

Minimal and maximal values at `k=100, 101` are (Note, that there is no limit for `dy` at `k -> Infinity` it is why there is `Out[1]=Interval[{0, 20}]`!),

```
minmaxy = {Limit[dy, k -> 100], Limit[dy, k -> 101]}

Out[]= {(5 (-1 + 1/E^100 - 1/E^99 + E))/(-1 + E^2), (
 5 (-1 + E + E^102 - E^103))/(E^101 (1 - E^2))}
```

We can simplifier last expression by hand neglected by `1/E^100, 1/E^99` and so on, finally we have

```
 miny = (5 (-1 + E))/(-1 + E^2); maxy = (
 5 (E^1 - E^2))/ (1 - E^2);

 maxy - miny // Simplify

Out[]= (5 (-1 + E))/(1 + E)
```